# Online bank tells me it's Apple devices that displays webpage incorrectly

Tags: web-browsing

My online bank is trying to convince me that it's because I have an Apple computer to log on to their service that's the reason for a table of transactions not displaying correctly:

> The website was formatted to be run using a 720p HD Ready monitor and
>   this would be why your Macintosh devices aren't showing the full
>   detail as they use a 16:10 Retina aspect ratio.

I don't buy it. Are they correct? Are Apple devices known to display web tables incorrectly? I don't see it on other online services.

Thanks,

Todd.

EDIT: I'm using Safari and Firefox. And have tried them on OSX 10.11 and 10.12

Comment: Let's call it horse apples. Best call would be that their site is using a whole bunch of Windows only 'tricks' rather than properly following correct practices. Test it on https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that with a page that requires a login. But I feel you might be right...

Comment: Is this happen with safari? Have you tried with another browser?

Comment: Yep, i'll edit to indicate.

Comment: If you've tried it with multiple browsers, then it's not an Apple issue.  It's more like a "cheap bank doesn't code correctly" issue.

Comment: I would suggest you tell your bank that screen resolution doesn't affect how a web page is displayed (other than if your resolution were too low to display everything on-screen at once) and then tell them their incompetent customer help desk is why you're closing your account.